# Причастный оборот и придаточное определительное в одном ряду могут стоять?

Tags: придаточное-предложение

Нельзя в одном предложении соединять при помощи союза и причастный оборот и придаточное определительное, начинающееся со слов который, которая, которое, которые.

Неправильно: На столе у Манилова лежала книга, открытая на одной и той же странице и которую он никогда не читал.

Правильно: На столе у Манилова лежала открытая на одной и той же странице книга, которую он никогда не читал.

А не исправлять предложение:

*На столе у него лежал журнал, открытый на одной и той же странице, который он никогда не читал.*

на

*На столе у него лежал открытый на одной и той же странице журнал, который он никогда не читал.*

будет ли ошибкой?

Answer (score 2):

Это *не* будет ошибкой, в исходном материале показан лишь один из возможных вариантов исправления. Недопустимость соединения исходных фрагментов **союзом "и"** обусловлена *разнородностью* их по форме; без союза их сосуществование возможно и без изменения порядка следования оборота. Если мешающее этому обстоятельство исправить другим способом (сделав первый оборот придаточным предложением), то возможен третий вариант, с этим самым союзом:

> На столе у Манилова лежала книга, *которая* была открыта на одной и той
>   же странице **и** *которую* он никогда не читал.